# Autowire Beans with application-test.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file, spring-camel

I have the following Test class, and my beans are always autowired according to the application.properties in my **src path**.

The simple attributes are correctly autowired (queueFrom, queueTo...) but the attribute **camelContext** is autowired with the principal **application.properties** file

I want to autowire my beans with a specific properties file in **test path**

This is the header of my Test class:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-north-connector-test.properties")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class LifeRouteITTest extends CamelTestSupport {

  private NotifyBuilder notify;

  @Value("${route.lifefrom}")
  private String queueFrom;
  @Value("${route.lifeto}")
  private String queueTo;
  @Value("${expected.liferoute.file.path}/")
  private String expectedFilePath;
  @Value("${input.liferoute.file.path}/")
  private String inputFilePath;

  @Autowired
  private CamelContext camelContext;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Spring boot looks for application.properties under src/main/resources. For tests, its src/test/resources. Spring boot automagically picks up files from these locations.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put your test properties in an `application.properties` file and place it in `src/test/resources`. The test properties would be loaded from there automatically.